# Some specific truncated strings are not matched via LIKE expression in SQL

Tags: php, mariadb

I seem to not be able to debug it, there are two columns of binary encoded BitTorrent info-hash strings in db, one is truncated to 20 bytes (Sha1 representation), the second is 32 bytes (sha2), so I do LIKE expression this way:

```
if (strlen($info_hash) == 32) {
    $is_bt_v2 = true;
} elseif (strlen($info_hash) == 20) {
    $is_bt_v2 = false;
}
$info_hash = rtrim(DB()->escape($info_hash), ' ');

$info_hash_where = $is_bt_v2 ? "WHERE tor.info_hash_v2 = '$info_hash'" : "WHERE tor.info_hash = '$info_hash' OR tor.info_hash_v2 LIKE '$info_hash%'";

$sql = "
    SELECT tor.topic_id, tor.poster_id, tor.tor_type, tor.info_hash, tor.info_hash_v2, u.*
    FROM " . BB_BT_TORRENTS . " tor
    LEFT JOIN " . BB_BT_USERS . " u ON u.auth_key = '$passkey_sql'
    $info_hash_where
    LIMIT 1
";
$row = DB()->fetch_row($sql);
```

$is_bt_v2 is just a marker with checked length of hash string, so it will be true if hash length will be 32 bytes in the future (currently not supported by standard) and the search will be performed only in v2 column for performance, else it first will be checked in v1 then v2 via LIKE expression.

In reality hash is always truncated to 20 bytes even if it is sha2, so it is being checked in both columns (only the second condition in $info_hash_where).

The thing is, if I search full 32 bytes string it will return the result, somehow it works with other v2 strings truncated to 20 bytes, but some specific strings are not found.

I spent a week checking the db settings (MariaDb), but I don't know what is happening.

Strings (v2):

Full: 97978479e7eba00af6f24953f6b94b229b556627167b710472ad4c9bc4ceac41 // Found

Truncated: 97978479e7eba00af6f24953f6b94b229b556627 // Found

Url encoded: %97%97%84y%e7%eb%a0%0a%f6%f2IS%f6%b9K%22%9bUf%27

---

Full: b5c69a98c0235cc2af0fa0c956a2984dc10410b1ab0eee46c9cb0c876d0c5189 // Found

Truncated: b5c69a98c0235cc2af0fa0c956a2984dc10410b1 // **NOT FOUND!**

Url encoded: %b5%c6%9a%98%c0%23%5c%c2%af%0f%a0%c9V%a2%98M%c1%04%10%b1

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32391315)

Comment: @Dharman All the SQL sanitizing happening in the other area of code which I didn't include

Comment: _"All the SQL sanitizing happening in the other area of code"_ - You shouldn't manually sanitize the data for SQL injection in your code at all. You should use prepared statements instead, as pointed out above. It's by far the most secure method.

Comment: There should be absolutely NO SQL sanitizing! Please use prepared statements.

Comment: Prepared statements with parameters is the robust method of sanitising variables for inclusion in a sql statement. Nothing else gives any guarantees. This has been standard practice for 20 years. It's unclear where you got the idea for any other approach.

Comment: Okay, will do, does anyone has an idea what the problem could be?